# list.add(String) in LinkedList doesnt work properly for me

Tags: java, string, for-loop, linked-list

I want write program with this functionality:
User will input how many things he have. He will input these things and things will be added to the list.
I made this code :

```
public class lists {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    LinkedList<String> list= new LinkedList<String>();
    System.out.println("How many things you have?");
    int size=input.nextInt();
    LinkedList<String> list= new LinkedList<String>();
    System.out.println("Enter those things");
    for(int c=1;c<=size;c++) list.add(input.nextLine().toString());     
        System.out.printf("%s",list);

}
```

}

For example Output for number 5 looks like this:

```
[, 1st Inputed, 2nd Inputed,3rd Inputed, 4nd inputed]
```

I want to know why the first String in the list is empty and it lets me input less things that I want. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your program will not compile because variable `list` is declared two times..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
 public class lists {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many things you have?");
        int size=input.nextInt();
        LinkedList<String> list= new LinkedList<String>();
        System.out.println("Enter those things");
        for(int c=0 ;c < size; c++)
        {
            String s = input.next();//use next() instead of nextLine()
            list.add(s);     
        }
            System.out.printf("%s",list);

       } 
    }
```

[`Scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) as described in official document is:

> **Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped.** This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the
>   beginning of the next line.

After `nextInt()` is called it isn't properly terminating the allocated line of memory. So when `nextLine()` is called first time it is actually terminating the previous line that actually had value in it -- entered via `nextInt()` rather than taking in a new `String` value.That's why the `String` at index `0` of `list` is blank. So , in order to carry on reading the entered value rather than the previous blank line (because of non-termination of value returned by `nextInt()`) you can use [`Scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) which according to official document states that:

> **Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.**

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `input.nextInt()` does not consume the trailing newline, so the first `input.nextLine()` returns an empty string.

There are several ways to work around this. I'll leave it as an exercise to figure out how best to do it.